# Why doesn't the snackbar close automatically?

Tags: flutter, snackbar

When I create a snackbar with action parameter it doesn't close automatically, even after the duration has ended.

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
  SnackBar(
    content: Text("An Expense Was Removed."),
    action: SnackBarAction(
      label: "Undo",
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  ),
```

When I remove the action parameter, it closes automatically as expected. What is the problem?

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
  SnackBar(
    content: Text("An Expense Was Removed."),
    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  ),
);
```

Comment: `A SnackBar with an action will not time out when TalkBack or VoiceOver are enabled. This is controlled by AccessibilityFeatures.accessibleNavigation.` as mentioned already @ https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBar-class.html

Comment: but how can I disable this ?

Comment: i think it's the same issue as this one https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/126756

Answer (score 0):

A snack bar with a button will not auto close/hide, but if you want to nevertheless have a button snack bar that hides, you can use a stateful widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class AutoHideSnackBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AutoHideSnackBarState createState() => _AutoHideSnackBarState();
}

class _AutoHideSnackBarState extends State<AutoHideSnackBar> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  Timer? _snackbarTimer;

  void _showSnackbar() {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text('Snackbar will be hidden after 5 seconds'),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'Hide',
          onPressed: () => _hideSnackbar(),
        ),
      ),
    );

    _snackbarTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      _hideSnackbar();
    });
  }

  void _hideSnackbar() {
    if (_snackbarTimer != null && _snackbarTimer!.isActive) {
      _snackbarTimer!.cancel();
    }
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Snackbar Hide Button Example')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _showSnackbar,
          child: Text('Show Snackbar'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class AutoHideSnackBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AutoHideSnackBarState createState() => _AutoHideSnackBarState();
}

class _AutoHideSnackBarState extends State<AutoHideSnackBar> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  Timer? _snackbarTimer;

  void _showSnackbar() {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text('Snackbar will be hidden after 5 seconds'),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'Hide',
          onPressed: () => _hideSnackbar(),
        ),
      ),
    );

    _snackbarTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      _hideSnackbar();
    });
  }

  void _hideSnackbar() {
    if (_snackbarTimer != null && _snackbarTimer!.isActive) {
      _snackbarTimer!.cancel();
    }
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Snackbar Hide Button Example')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _showSnackbar,
          child: Text('Show Snackbar'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The button on the snackbar hides the snackbar, so you can hide the snackbar before the duration runs out.